# Order by Not working on Temporary Table in MySql

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I got data in my table as per follows I want to order by dDistance, I tried few things like CAST(dDistance as Decimal) or CAST (dDistance as FLOAT).

Also I tried

`select dDistance from yourtable
order by dDistance + 0`

but its not at all working

And Schema for TransmitterPointsData is:

[image]

Query is as follows:

```
CREATE  TEMPORARY TABLE TempTable Select tpd.Latitude as Latitude ,tpd.Longitude as Longitude,tpd.CoverageID as coverageID from TransmitterPointsData tpd
```

Another TempTable DistTable

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE DistTable select te.Latitude,
    te.Longitude, 
    te.CoverageID,
    POWER((x),2)  as A,
    POWER((z),2)  as C,
    POWER((y),2))) as dDistance,
    from TempTable te;
```

To get output:

```
SELECT * from DistTable order by CAST(dDistance as DECIMAL) ASC;
```

I can see following table but not Order by operation

[image: MySql Table]

Any Help?
Thank You

Comment: What data type is `dDistance`?

Comment: Datatype for dDistance is REAL (Correction)

Comment: Then it should work fine. Please edit your question with the query that is not working, and explain how is it "not working"? Please use text rather than images.

Comment: Please add table structure with some sample data.

Comment: Edited Post.. Anything else you want?

Comment: Can you provide a few rows of sample data from `TempTable` in text format (not an image)?

Comment: Also what version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: Please add table structure and data of table **TempTable**

Comment: SQL Version 5.5.61

Comment: Edited Post to show what is TempData and What is TransmitterPointsData schema

Comment: Instead of adding all this stuff, could you please add sample data  for **DistTable** this table ?  with proper table structure ?

Comment: The output you see is from DistTable only.

Comment: What are `x`, `y` and `z` in your DistTable creation query?

Comment: Its User Entered Values those are int. Parameters of procedure

Comment: If `y` is an `INT` how can `POWER(y,2)` be a number with non-zero decimal places?

Answer (score 1):

I got Solution.
I changed select Statement like below

```
SELECT dt.* from DistTable AS dt ORDER BY dt.dDistance ASC;
```